# Data Representation in LC-3

Tags: lc3, data-representation

I was doing my exam prep and I have come across a problem that ive been having issues with mainly because of the lack of info provided. The question is

b.What integer does the 16 bit word F751 represent in the LC-3?

So do we convert the base 16 to base 10 or base 2, Im not really sure how to do this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take f751 and convert to binary

1111 0111 0101 0001

The most significant bit is 1 so we know the number is negative, so take the 2s complement

0000 1000 1010 1111

And Convert to decimal -2223

Comment: For a hex value like 01BD you would not have to find two's compliment as it is  positive value correct you can go straight to decimal. Correct? @Brandon

Comment: Correct. Good luck on your exams!

Answer (score 0):

The High digit is greater or equal to 8 so the number is negative.
Take the complement to F (fifteen) of each digit:  f751

f give 0

7 give 8

5 give A

1 give E

08AE is the 1 complement

08AF is the 2 complement which is in decimal -2223

This prevent to convert to binary